# Inheriting traits classes after a slight change in template type

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, c++17, template-meta-programming

Given

```
template <int...> struct Z;   template <int...> struct Q;
template <std::size_t...> struct I;
```

Suppose we want

```
accumulated_sums<Z<1,2,3,4,5>, Q>::type
```

to be

```
Q<1,3,6,10,15>
```

and

```
accumulated<I<1,2,3,4,5>, std::integer_sequence>::type
```

to be

```
std::index_sequence<1,3,6,10,15>
```

Is there a way to define the `accumulated` class by some inheritance scheme from the `accumulated_sums` class?  They operate exactly the same way, with the only difference being the template type `template <T...> class` for `accumulated_sums` vs the slightly different `template <typename U, U...> class` for `accumulated`.  Otherwise, I have to define the two classes separately even though their definitions are essentially identical.  There should be some way to define it just once for both classes.  Here is my fully compiling code for both classes, and you can see that they are essentially identical in code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

namespace detail {
    template <typename Pack> struct sequence_traits;

    template <typename T, template <T...> class Z, T... Is>
    struct sequence_traits<Z<Is...>> {
        using type = T;
        template <T... Js>
        using templ_type = Z<Js...>;
    };
}

// accumulated_sums
template <typename T, typename Output, template <T...> class, T...> struct accumulated_sums_h;

template <typename T, template <T...> class Z, template <T...> class Q, T Sum, T... Is>
struct accumulated_sums_h<T, Z<Sum, Is...>, Q> {
    using type = Q<Is..., Sum>;
};

template <typename T, template <T...> class Z, T Sum, T... Is, template <T...> class Q, T Next, T... Rest>
struct accumulated_sums_h<T, Z<Sum, Is...>, Q, Next, Rest...> :
    accumulated_sums_h<T, Z<Sum + Next, Is..., Sum>, Q, Rest...> {};

template <typename Sequence,
    template <typename detail::sequence_traits<Sequence>::type...> class = detail::sequence_traits<Sequence>::template templ_type>
    struct accumulated_sums;

template <typename T, template <T...> class Z, T First, T... Rest, template <T...> class Q>
struct accumulated_sums<Z<First, Rest...>, Q> :
    accumulated_sums_h<T, Z<First>, Q, Rest...> {};

// accumulated
template <typename T, typename Output, template <typename U, U...> class, T...> struct accumulated_h;

template <typename T, template <T...> class Z, template <typename U, U...> class Q, T Sum, T... Is>
struct accumulated_h<T, Z<Sum, Is...>, Q> {
    using type = Q<T, Is..., Sum>;
};

template <typename T, template <T...> class Z, T Sum, T... Is, template <typename U, U...> class Q, T Next, T... Rest>
struct accumulated_h<T, Z<Sum, Is...>, Q, Next, Rest...> :
    accumulated_h<T, Z<Sum + Next, Is..., Sum>, Q, Rest...> {};

template <typename Sequence, template <typename U, U...> class Q> struct accumulated;

template <typename T, template <T...> class Z, T First, T... Rest, template <typename U, U...> class Q>
struct accumulated<Z<First, Rest...>, Q> :
    accumulated_h<T, Z<First>, Q, Rest...> {};

// Testing
template <int...> struct Z;
template <int...> struct Q;
template <std::size_t...> struct I;

int main() {
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << std::is_same<
        accumulated_sums<Z<1,2,3,4,5>, Q>::type,
        Q<1,3,6,10,15>
    >::value << '\n';  // true

    std::cout << std::is_same<
        accumulated_sums<Z<1,2,3,4,5>>::type,
        Z<1,3,6,10,15>
    >::value << '\n';  // true

    std::cout << std::is_same<
        accumulated<Z<1,2,3,4,5>, std::integer_sequence>::type,
        std::integer_sequence<int, 1,3,6,10,15>
    >::value << '\n';  // true

    std::cout << std::is_same<
        accumulated<I<1,2,3,4,5>, std::integer_sequence>::type,
        std::index_sequence<1,3,6,10,15>
    >::value << '\n';  // true
}
```

Comment: @max66 [Compiles just fine in C++17](https://godbolt.org/g/5tKv7Z)

Comment: @Justin - thanks; right: C++17

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you accept to pass `Q<>` instead of `Q` and `std::integer_sequence<int>` (or `std::integer_sequence<std::size_t>`) instead of `std::integer_sequence` (so a template type instead of a template-template type) you can fork the cases (with or without a first type template) at bottom (see `accumulated_h2` in the following example) and not at top

So you can use `accumulated` for both cases and trow away `accumulated_sum`.

The following is a full working example.

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

namespace detail
 {
   template <typename Pack>
   struct sequence_traits;

   template <typename T, template <T...> class Z, T... Is>
   struct sequence_traits<Z<Is...>>
    { using templ_empty = Z<>; };
 }

// accumulated

template <typename T, typename, T...>
struct accumulated_h2;

template <typename T, template <typename, T ...> class Q, T ... Ts>
struct accumulated_h2<T, Q<T>, Ts...>
 { using type = Q<T, Ts...>; };

template <typename T, template <T ...> class Q, T ... Ts>
struct accumulated_h2<T, Q<>, Ts...>
 { using type = Q<Ts...>; };

template <typename T, typename, typename, T...>
struct accumulated_h;

template <typename T, template <T...> class Z, typename C, T Sum, T... Is>
struct accumulated_h<T, Z<Sum, Is...>, C>
 { using type = typename accumulated_h2<T, C, Is..., Sum>::type; };

template <typename T, template <T...> class Z, T Sum, T... Is,
          typename C, T Next, T... Rest>
struct accumulated_h<T, Z<Sum, Is...>, C, Next, Rest...>
   : accumulated_h<T, Z<Sum + Next, Is..., Sum>, C, Rest...>
 { };

template <typename T,
          typename = typename detail::sequence_traits<T>::templ_empty>
struct accumulated;

template <typename T, template <T...> class Z, T First,
          T... Rest, typename C>
struct accumulated<Z<First, Rest...>, C>
   : accumulated_h<T, Z<First>, C, Rest...>
 { };

// Testing

template <int...>
struct Z;

template <int...>
struct Q;

template <std::size_t...>
struct I;

int main ()
 {
   static_assert(std::is_same<
      accumulated<Z<1,2,3,4,5>, Q<>>::type,
      Q<1,3,6,10,15>>::value, "!");
   static_assert(std::is_same<
      accumulated<Z<1,2,3,4,5>>::type,
      Z<1,3,6,10,15>>::value, "!");    
   static_assert(std::is_same<
      accumulated<Z<1,2,3,4,5>, std::integer_sequence<int>>::type,
      std::integer_sequence<int, 1,3,6,10,15>>::value, "!");
   static_assert(std::is_same<
      accumulated<I<1,2,3,4,5>, std::integer_sequence<std::size_t>>::type,
      std::index_sequence<1,3,6,10,15>>::value, "!");
 }
```

**-- EDIT --**

The OP ask

> And how to fork the cases so that `accumulated<std::integer_sequence<T, 1,2,3,4,5>>::type` is `std::integer_sequence<T, 1,3,6,10,15>`, where `T` is any integral type?

I've seen your solution and I've prepared another one, not a lot different: throwed away the old `Z`, I've substituted it with `std::integer_sequence` instead your `squeeze`.

The following is my code.

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

namespace detail
 {
   template <typename Pack>
   struct sequence_traits;

   template <typename T, template <typename, T...> class Z, T... Is>
   struct sequence_traits<Z<T, Is...>>
    { using templ_empty = Z<T>; };

   template <typename T, template <T...> class Z, T... Is>
   struct sequence_traits<Z<Is...>>
    { using templ_empty = Z<>; };
 }

// accumulated

template <typename T, typename, T...>
struct accumulated_h2;

template <typename T, template <typename, T ...> class Q, T ... Ts>
struct accumulated_h2<T, Q<T>, Ts...>
 { using type = Q<T, Ts...>; };

template <typename T, template <T ...> class Q, T ... Ts>
struct accumulated_h2<T, Q<>, Ts...>
 { using type = Q<Ts...>; };

template <typename T, typename, typename, T...>
struct accumulated_h;

template <typename T, typename C, T Sum, T... Is>
struct accumulated_h<T, std::integer_sequence<T, Sum, Is...>, C>
 { using type = typename accumulated_h2<T, C, Is..., Sum>::type; };

template <typename T, T Sum, T... Is, typename C, T Next, T... Rest>
struct accumulated_h<T, std::integer_sequence<T, Sum, Is...>, C, Next,
                     Rest...>
   : accumulated_h<T, std::integer_sequence<T, Sum + Next, Is..., Sum>,
                   C, Rest...>
 { };

template <typename T,
          typename = typename detail::sequence_traits<T>::templ_empty>
struct accumulated;

template <typename T, template <T...> class Z, T First,
          T... Rest, typename C>
struct accumulated<Z<First, Rest...>, C>
   : accumulated_h<T, std::integer_sequence<T, First>, C, Rest...>
 { };

template <typename T, template <typename, T...> class Z, T First,
          T... Rest, typename C>
struct accumulated<Z<T, First, Rest...>, C>
   : accumulated_h<T, std::integer_sequence<T, First>, C, Rest...>
 { };

// Testing

template <int...>
struct Z;

template <int...>
struct Q;

template <std::size_t...>
struct I;

int main ()
 {
   static_assert(std::is_same<
      accumulated<Z<1,2,3,4,5>, Q<>>::type,
      Q<1,3,6,10,15>>::value, "!");
   static_assert(std::is_same<
      accumulated<Z<1,2,3,4,5>>::type,
      Z<1,3,6,10,15>>::value, "!");    
   static_assert(std::is_same<
      accumulated<Z<1,2,3,4,5>, std::integer_sequence<int>>::type,
      std::integer_sequence<int, 1,3,6,10,15>>::value, "!");
   static_assert(std::is_same<
      accumulated<I<1,2,3,4,5>, std::integer_sequence<std::size_t>>::type,
      std::index_sequence<1,3,6,10,15>>::value, "!");
   static_assert(std::is_same<
      accumulated<std::index_sequence<1,2,3,4,5>>::type,
      std::index_sequence<1,3,6,10,15>>::value);
   static_assert(std::is_same<
      accumulated<std::index_sequence<1,2,3,4,5>, I<>>::type,
      I<1,3,6,10,15>>::value);
 }
```

Comment: And how to fork the cases so that `accumulated<std::integer_sequence<T, 1,2,3,4,5>>::type` is `std::integer_sequence<T, 1,3,6,10,15>`, where `T` is any integral type? `template <typename T, template <typename U, U...> class Z, T First,
          T... Rest, typename C>
struct accumulated<Z<T, First, Rest...>, C>` inherits from what (without duplicating the implementation)?

Comment: Ok, I've found the adapted solution of yours to give what I want (without repeat implementation).  I added it as an answer.

Comment: @prestokeys - answer modified but my improved solution is, essentially, equivalent to yours

Comment: @ max66   Yes.  We were both working on the new solution at the same time.  Thanks.  I've accepted your answer.

Answer (score 1):

In adapting max66's solution, I allowed, for example, `accumulated<std::integer_sequence<T, 1,2,3,4,5>>::type` to be `std::integer_sequence<T, 1,3,6,10,15>`, where T is any integral type. Repeat implementation has been avoided. The following compiles with GCC 7.2:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

namespace detail {
   template <typename Pack>
   struct sequence_traits;

   template <typename T, template <T...> class Z, T... Is>
   struct sequence_traits<Z<Is...>>
    { using templ_empty = Z<>; };

   template <typename T, template <typename U, U...> class Z, T... Is>
   struct sequence_traits<Z<T, Is...>>
    { using templ_empty = Z<T>; };
 }

// accumulated
template <typename T, typename EmptyContainer, T...>
struct accumulated_h2;

template <typename T, template <typename U, U...> class Q, T ... Ts>
struct accumulated_h2<T, Q<T>, Ts...>
 { using type = Q<T, Ts...>; };

template <typename T, template <T...> class Q, T ... Ts>
struct accumulated_h2<T, Q<>, Ts...>
 { using type = Q<Ts...>; };

template <typename T, typename Sequence, typename, T...>
struct accumulated_h;

template <typename T, template <T...> class Z, typename EmptyContainer, T Sum, T... Is>
struct accumulated_h<T, Z<Sum, Is...>, EmptyContainer>
 { using type = typename accumulated_h2<T, EmptyContainer, Is..., Sum>::type; };

template <typename T, template <T...> class Z, T Sum, T... Is,
          typename EmptyContainer, T Next, T... Rest>
struct accumulated_h<T, Z<Sum, Is...>, EmptyContainer, Next, Rest...>
   : accumulated_h<T, Z<Sum + Next, Is..., Sum>, EmptyContainer, Rest...>
 { };

template <typename Sequence,
          typename = typename detail::sequence_traits<Sequence>::templ_empty>
struct accumulated;

template <typename T, template <T...> class Z, T First,
          T... Rest, typename EmptyContainer>
struct accumulated<Z<First, Rest...>, EmptyContainer>
   : accumulated_h<T, Z<First>, EmptyContainer, Rest...>
 { };

////// Added //////
template <typename T> struct squeeze {
    template <T... Is> struct Z;
    template <T... Is>
    using templ_type = Z<Is...>;
};

template <typename T, template <typename U, U...> class Z, T First,
          T... Rest, typename EmptyContainer>
struct accumulated<Z<T, First, Rest...>, EmptyContainer>
   : accumulated_h<T, typename squeeze<T>::template templ_type<First>, EmptyContainer, Rest...>
 { };
/////////

// Testing
template <int...>
struct Z;

template <int...>
struct Q;

template <std::size_t...>
struct I;

int main ()
 {
   static_assert(std::is_same<
      accumulated<Z<1,2,3,4,5>, Q<>>::type,
      Q<1,3,6,10,15>>::value);
   static_assert(std::is_same<
      accumulated<Z<1,2,3,4,5>>::type,
      Z<1,3,6,10,15>>::value);    
   static_assert(std::is_same<
      accumulated<Z<1,2,3,4,5>, std::integer_sequence<int>>::type,
      std::integer_sequence<int, 1,3,6,10,15>>::value);
   static_assert(std::is_same<
      accumulated<I<1,2,3,4,5>, std::integer_sequence<std::size_t>>::type,
      std::index_sequence<1,3,6,10,15>>::value);

    // Added
    static_assert(std::is_same<
      accumulated<std::index_sequence<1,2,3,4,5>>::type,
      std::index_sequence<1,3,6,10,15>>::value);    
 }
```

Update:  Thanks to max66's ideas, I've generalized even further to any number of sequences:  https://ideone.com/FBWApu
The code compiles with GCC 7.2, but ideone fails because it only uses C++14.